# Testing multiple viewport sizes with Django/Selenium

Tags: python, css, django, selenium, testing

I'm trying to test characteristics of certain UI elements given different viewport sizes and media defined in CSS. I have a setup function to instantiate a headless Chrome browser with I believe a default viewport size of 800x600:

```
class NewDesktopVisitorTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.chrome_options = Options()
        self.chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.chrome_options)
```

This works well for testing what I would consider the desktop version of a page, but I'd also like to make sure the mobile version renders as I'd expect. I can create a completely separate class with a different setup and specify the viewport size like so:

```
class NewMobileVisitorTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.chrome_options = Options()
        self.chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=375,800')
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.chrome_options)
```

This has the benefit of very cleanly showing where a given test is failing (i.e. desktop or mobile). The trouble is that I want the exact same tests to run against both (and potentially multiple) viewport sizes, and I don't want to have to maintain the exact same tests in multiple classes.

Most of my searches for parameterized testing yield solutions for running the same tests against different data sets, but I've yet to find examples of solutions for setting up and running the same tests against multiple starting configurations.

I'm hesitant (although not unwilling) to switch to a different testing framework or install additional packages only to solve for this specific case.

Has anyone found a straightforward solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run my different sizes in a `for` loop to iterate a `list` of window sizes so I don't have to write the same tests over again.

```py
XS = [320, 568]
SM = [568, 320]
MD = [768, 1024]
LG = [1024, 768]
XL = [1200, 750]

WINDOW_SIZES = [XS, SM, MD, LG, XL]

# Loops through all of the sizes.
for window in WINDOW_SIZES:

    # Set the window size       [320,568], etc...
    driver.set_window_size(window[0],window[1])

    # Load the page you want to test.
    driver.get('mypage')

    # rest of test assertions
```

I also made a method that makes this a little easier:

```py
def get_page(self, url_extention, window=XS):
    return (
        driver.set_window_size(window[0], window[1]),
        driver.get(self.live_server_url + url_extention)
    )
```

Then in the test I can run

```py
self.get_page('mysite', window=window) # or MD if that is all I want to test
```

I usually start with all of them, and then (similar to bootstrap) as I move up in window size changing what I need to. So for `MD` and up:

```py
# Tests small sizes.
def test_mypage(self):
    self.get_page('mysite', window=window)

    self.assert('Assertions for all sizes')

# Tests larger sizes.
def test_mypage_MD(self):
    self.get_page('mysite', window=[MD,LG,XL])

    self.assert('The things that are different from the previous test')
```

P.S - I know my breakpoints are different than Bootstraps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yeah, I'm a total novice, so more detail would be awesome when you have a chance